How to trace variables with print from gpu parallel (CUDA)
When you print, in parallel, (CUDA) all of the threads fire at once.
This makes it very difficult when printing output, so as to trace a variable, because the output is essentially out of order.
Instead of:

t1 ouput_1
t1 output_2
t1 output_3

You get:

t1 output_1
t2 output_1
t3 output_1

You can imagine how difficult this is when you have dozens of threads running 10s of lines of code pushing literally 1000s of lines of output.
So far I've just been printing all of a kernel's variables in one line.
I've already run into problems doing this which can be seen
here
The only other solution I can think of is to tag each line, output to a text file, and write a program to re-order the data.
This would be incredibly time consuming and process heavy.
Is there any better way to print data to trace variables when the prints are firing in parallel? I am using Nvidia's cuda toolkit in plain C.

you can use a critical section to group items from one thread together.  I'm sure you will be able to criticize almost any approach; this problem is not unique to CUDA but applies to use of printf in other thread-parallel settings such as OpenMP.   However a critical section would allow the transformation goal you describe in your question, for some cases.  It's not a zero-performance impact, but if you are doing printf from kernel code, I would normally expect that performance isn't a critical issue at that juncture.

@RobertCrovella What I think I will do is just lock the entire kernel and have it run one thread at a time and minimize my data size which should be sufficient for debugging. I could see building a script like yours but I think sql would be a better long-term choice when I eventually get to that point.

Make sure you include a '\n' at the end of every print statement, and tag every line with the thread info.
I use the following code to do printing.
#define println(format, ...) \
  printf("T:%02i W:%02i B:%02i Line:%4i " format "\n", \ 
    threadIdx.x, threadIdx.x / 32, blockIdx.x, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
//note no trailing ;

If you do your printing in a single printf statement with a trailing \n, CUDA will always print that line separate from the lines of other threads and never intermingles prints.
Do not split the printing into multiple lines, because then output from other threads will be interspersed.
If you find that you need more arguments than the 32 - 4 = 28 that you have, then you and do a format, create some substring, and use a %s argument to paste in your printf. Or, even better just print more lines.
This can make your output more verbose, but you can always post process them. The labeling of thread info is vital, because otherwise the output is useless for debugging.
That said, I would advise against reordering the output in post processing, because you lose the ordering info (which threads run in what order), that can be very useful when debugging issues.

The issue is trying to track 1 thread when potentially 100s of them are running at once. Even if it's just one print (which is hard) it comes out in a 100 line gob, even if it is ordered by thread number. Trying to read pages and pages of output in gobs like that to track the output of a single thread is basically impossible.

It's also very difficult to debug a kernel with just 1 print statement. If you need to print in a loop, for example, you multiply those gobs by the entire iter count.

I basically need something like an sql database for the ouput so I can run sql queries to view individual threads or values.

@bigcodeszzer Maybe using a debugger is better than all this complexity?

@paleonix there are debuggers that can do this?

I could use scanf or regex or even sql but this would also make each run take a very long time which would be horrible.

@bigcodeszzer Depends on what you mean by "this". But generally debuggers can do a lot and as far as I know cuda-gdb is extensible using Python.

Tracking many lines is not impossible. I regularly use printf to track stuff, on kernels with > 300 blocks, each having 64 threads. You need to increase the buffer for printf. (I set it to 1 GiB), and then flush it to a file. You can analyze this just fine. You can also collate data in shared memory and then have a single thread per warp/block print a summary.
